# regex not working

Tags: c, regex

This is the string I want to match

> str = "hello_my_world";

```
         regex_t reg;
         if (regcomp(&reg, pattern, REG_EXTENDED | REG_ICASE) != 0) {
             exit (-1);
         }

         if (regexec(&reg, str, 0, NULL, 0) != 0) {
             regfree(&reg);
             /* did not match */
         }

         regfree(&reg);
     }
```

if pattern is `hello_*` it returns true. but if pattern is `hello_*_world` it doesn't...is that expected?

how can I match it?

Comment: @Joe Holloway: right there in the question

Comment: Thanks for answers all of you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read up on regex syntax. The pattern `hello_*_world` will match "hello", followed by zero or more underscores, followed by yet an underscore, followed by "world".

What you want for a pattern is `hello_.*_world`, which maches "hello_" followed by zero or more arbitrary chraracters, followed by "_world".

The pattern `hello_*` matches, because your string *contains* a "hello" that is followed by zero or more underscores.

Answer (score 2):

Regex * is different from glob *: it means "0 or more of the *previous* atom"

So I think you want:

```
hello_.*_world
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a pattern of `hello_.+_world` or `hello_[A-Za-z]+_world`.

The * applies to the char before it (0 or more occurrences), so it matches `hello_world`, `hello__world`, `hello___world`, etc.